# How to emulate reading an NFC tag on an Android emulator

Tags: android

There is an application that needs to be covered with autotests. In the UI you need to emulate reading the NFC tag. Do you have any ideas on how to write this on the Android emulator? Maybe there are some instructions. Automation in JAVA. Android API30

looking for solutions

Answer (score 0):

The is no current solution for NFC on the Emulator.

You need a real phone and manual tests (technically depending on the NFC Tag hardware you might be able to drive a USB reader with Tag emulation capabilities to replace presenting a physical Tag to a Physical phone).

Also probably technically possible that you might be able program and build your own emulator with NFC.